# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка

Tags: sqlite

```
cursor.execute(f"""Update users set status = "paid", subscribe_start = "{date_start}", 
                       subscribe_finish = "{date_fininsh}", 
                       [transaction] = "{tranzaktion}", 
                       WHERE user_id = "{message.from_user.id}" """)
```

Comment: " [transaction] = "{tranzaktion}"," - не надо "," перед where и [] тоже